# AWS Redis + uWSGI behind NGINX - high load

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, redis, uwsgi, redis-py

I'm running a python application (flask + redis-py) with uwsgi + nginx and using aws elasticache (redis 2.8.24).

while trying to improve my application response time, I've noticed that under high load (500 request per second/for 30 seconds using loader.io) I'm losing requests (for this test i'm using just a single server without load balancer, 1 uwsgi instance, 4 processes, on purpose for testing).
[image: stress test]

I've dug a little deeper and found out that under this load, some requests to ElastiCache are slow.
for example:

- normal load: cache_set time 0.000654935836792
- heavy load: cache_set time 0.0122258663177
  **this does not happen for all requests, just randomly occurres..**

My AWS ElastiCache is based on 2 nodes on cache.m4.xlarge (default AWS configuration settings).
See current clients connected in the last 3 hours:
[image: aws elasticache clients]

I think this doesn't make sense as currently 14 servers (8 of them with high traffic of XX RPS use this cluster), **I would expect to see a much higher client rate.**

uWSGI config (Version 2.0.5.1)

```
processes = 4
enable-threads = true
threads = 20
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
harakiri = 10
max-requests = 5000
thread-stacksize = 2048
thunder-lock = true
max-fd = 150000
# currently disabled for testing
#cheaper-algo = spare2
#cheaper = 2
#cheaper-initial = 2
#workers = 4
#cheaper-step = 1
```

Nginx is just a web proxy to uWSGI using unix socket.

This is how I open a connection to redis:

```
rdb = [
    redis.StrictRedis(host='server-endpoint', port=6379, db=0),
    redis.StrictRedis(host='server-endpoint', port=6379, db=1)
]
```

This is how I set a value for example:

```
def cache_set(key, subkey, val, db, cache_timeout=DEFAULT_TIMEOUT):
    t = time.time()
    merged_key = key + ':' + subkey
    res = rdb[db].set(merged_key, val, cache_timeout)
    print 'cache_set time ' + str(time.time() - t)
    return res

cache_set('prefix', 'key_name', 'my glorious value', 0, 20)
```

This is how I get a value:

```
def cache_get(key, subkey, db, _eval=False):
    t = time.time()
    merged_key = key + ':' + subkey
    val = rdb[db].get(merged_key)
    if _eval:
        if val:
            val = eval(val)
        else:  # None
            val = 0
    print 'cache_get time ' + str(time.time() - t)
    return val

cache_get('prefix', 'key_name', 0)
```

Version:

- uWSGI: 2.0.5.1
- Flask: 0.11.1
- redis-py: 2.10.5
- Redis: 2.8.24

**So the conclude:**

1. Why AWS clients count is low if 14 servers are connected, each with 4 processes, and each of them opens a connection to 8 different database within the redis cluster
2. What causes the requests response time to climb?
3. Would appreciate any advise regarding ElastiCache and/or uWSGI performance under heavy load

Comment: Orz, were you able to find a solution to this? I'm facing the exact same problem. Literally...nginx+flask+uwsgi has been fine, but since I added in redis on Elasticache I'm facing issues of long running queries in Elasticache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

So, if I got it right, in my case the problem was not Elasticache requests but uWSGI memory usage.

**Long Answer**

I've installed [uwsgitop](https://github.com/xrmx/uwsgitop) with this setup:

```
### Stats
### ---
### disabled by default
### To see stats run: uwsgitop /tmp/uwsgi_stats.socket
### uwsgitop must be install (pip install uwsgitop)
stats = /tmp/uwsgi_stats.socket
```

this will expose uwsgi stats to uwsgitop.

I then used [loader.io](http://loader.io) to stress test the application with 350-500 requests/second.

What I discovered with my previous configuration is that uWSGI workers kept growing in used memory size until the memory choked and then the cpu spiked. new workers that needed to re-spawn also demanded cpu which cause some sort of overload on the servers - which caused nginx to timeout and close those connections.

So I did some research and config modification till I managed to get the setup below, that currently manages ~650rps on each instance with ~13ms response time which is great for me.

*** My application used (still uses some) disk pickled dat files, some of them were heavy to load - i've reduced disk dependency to minimum ***

For anyone who might see it in the future - if you need fast responses - asynchronize everything you can. for ex, use celery+rabbitmq for any databases requests if possible

uWSGI Configuration:

```
listen = 128
processes = 8
threads = 2
max-requests = 10000
reload-on-as = 4095
reload-mercy = 5
#reload-on-rss = 1024
limit-as = 8192
cpu-affinity = 3
thread-stacksize = 1024
max-fd = 250000
buffer-size = 30000
thunder-lock = true
vacuum = true
enable-threads = true
no-orphans = true
die-on-term = true
```

NGINX relevant parts:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 4;
worker_rlimit_nofile 20000;
thread_pool my_threads threads=16;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    accept_mutex off;
    # determines how much clients will be served per worker
    # max clients = worker_connections * worker_processes
    # max clients is also limited by the number of socket connections available on the system (~64k)
    worker_connections 19000;

    # optmized to serve many clients with each thread, essential for linux -- for testing environment
    use epoll;

    # accept as many connections as possible, may flood worker connections if set too low -- for testing environment
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    ...
    aio                     threads;
    sendfile                on;
    sendfile_max_chunk      512k;
    tcp_nopush              on;
    tcp_nodelay             on;
    keepalive_timeout       5 5;
    keepalive_requests      0;
    types_hash_max_size     2048;
    send_timeout            15;
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you explain cpu-affinity and how it should be considered and used to optimize uWSGI? Our app isn't necessarily thread safe so we're not configuring threads, just worker processes.  Our production server (EC2) has 8 vCPU's (4 physical CPU's).  Doing our best to optimize but some of the uWSGI config is a black box and hard to find documentation.  Any other big difference makers on the config?